# Possible htaccess configuration issue for HTTPS websites by WP Fastest Cache plugin?

Tags: plugins, htaccess, cache

I am using WP Fastest Cache plugin for my HTTPS website. The plugin once activated adds several lines of code to the htaccess file. I doubt the presence of **RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on** in the below segment. Do these lines mean HTTPS urls will not be cached? Is this is a configuration issue on the side of the plugin?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/){2}$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !comment_author_
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !woocommerce_items_in_cart
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !safirmobilswitcher=mobil
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html" [L]
```

Comment: this is not a wordpress development question, but a generic htaccess question, for which a different stack will be a better place to ask. But obviously it would be way better to just ask the plugin's author

Comment: But I could see several questions pertaining to plugins on this stack. Moreover, already I have raised a query with the plugin author but  haven't got a reply from the author so far. Hence, my thought was to debug myself based on responses I get from stack. Kindly advise.

Comment: Ok, now I have added a specific query focusing only on htaccess part in webmasters stack. That should be fine I think.

Answer (score 1):

> Do these lines mean HTTPS urls will not be cached?

Well, it certainly means that on *most servers* that have an SSL cert installed, the URL will not be rewritten to `/wp-content/cache/all/<requested-URL-path>/index.html`. If that means the cache will be bypassed, then yes, it prevents caching.

The idea of not caching HTTPS requests would seem to be very outdated.

However, the [WP Fastest Cache plugin page](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fastest-cache/) does include "SSL support" as one of its features and further down the page explicitly states: "Yes, it is compatible with Http Secure (https).". So, there is perhaps more to this than that presented here?

WP support query posted by the OP (currently unanswered):
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/use-of-rewritecond-https-on/

Comment: Yes, I am waiting for the plugin author to respond on the WordPress support. As of now, the only logical conclusion seems HTTPS pages are handled in PHP and not at MOD_REWRITE. I wonder if there is any specific reason for different approaches for HTTP and HTTPS pages.